# About symmetric part of a non-symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a nonsymmetric positive definite matrix. Is the symmetric part of $A$, $H=(A+A^T)/2$, a positive definite matrix?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that for the skew part $S$

$$x^tSx=0 \quad \forall x$$

Comment: How does it help? Thanks.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician We can always divide any matrix as the sum of a symmetric matrix H and an skew symmetric matrix S. From here the result follows.